# Interface as argument - how to find which class implements it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working at modifying a large ASP.NET Core application. This application has a lot of interfaces, and there are some classes where all the properties are defined as interfaces.

I managed to step into the method I'm trying to modify once, but I haven't managed to do it again. I really need to find out which class implements this particular interface so I can examine it.

Is there a way that I can log the class name implementing the interface to the console/output?

Comment: do you have source code ? if you do, simply search all solution/project by name of the interface class, example interface IFile { }, then search by "IFile"

Comment: During runtime you can use GetType:

         public bool Test(ISample sample)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sample.GetType().FullName);
            }

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can right-click on interface name to open context menu and then choose `Go To Implementation`. It will show all implementations it can find. But it searches only in current solution. If you want to do it programmatically, go with @Markus Meyer's solution.

Comment: If you want to `Go To Implementation`,you can also press and hold the `ctrl`,and left click